# Bash get words after keys

Tags: bash, parsing, dependencies

## Bash get words after keys

I am writing a bash script to analyze my bash scripts. The analysis should print out all of the dependencies of the bash script being analyzed.

To do this I need to extract all of the "commands" (package names) from the script. What I would like to do is:

1. Print out the first word of each line: `awk '{print $1}'`
2. Print out the first word that comes after a pipe: `?`
3. Print out the first word that comes after a sub-shell: `?`
4. Ignore comments (this is not the best way): `grep -v '#'`

Goal 1 could be rephrased as:

1. Print out the first word that comes after a newline: `awk '{print $1}'`
   In general I would like to be able to:

- print out the first word that comes after a `<key>`

## Example

If the input file is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# My script
printf "Hello World\n" # First line
strings <<< "Hello World" | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/Hello/Goodbye/'
echo $(cat <<< "Hello World")
```

The output should be:

```
printf
strings
awk
sed
echo
cat
```

## Efficiency

Ideally I would like to search through the file only once. I have a version of this tool working right now, but for large bash scripts/projects it reads all files three times through (Checking for each of the three conditions mentioned above).

Current Version:

```sh
sed 's/|/\n/g; s/#/\n#/g; s/\$(/\n/g' ${FILENAME} \
  | sed 's/^[ \t]*//; /^#/d' \
  | awk '{print $1}' \
  | sort -u
```

Comment: You mentioned that you have a Python script for this which reads files three times. Maybe you should post your Python script code too and add python tag in the post.

Comment: You are basically trying to parse the bash script. I think it should be possible to handle all the conditions in one pass.

Comment: I am working on a solution in `bash`. I posted an inefficient bash solution for reference

Comment: You can read the file line by line in a for loop and process each line for each of the three conditions.

Comment: What do you mean by `<key>`? Do you mean words like `if` and `while`? But the more important question is: Do you care about how precise your tool is? Because an accurate inventory would require an accurate parse of the source being analysed, and you're not going to be able to achieve an accurate parse with a simple shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for command in input_file; do
    awk '!/^#/ {print $1}' input_file
    awk -v RS="[|(]" '!/^#/ {print $1}' input_file
done
```

Explanation:

- 1st `awk` prints column1 if the line does not start with a comment/pound sign `#`
- 2nd `awk` changes the record separator `RS` to `|` and `(` which then allows me to grab the other commands after a pipe `|` or open bracket `(` as column 1

**Output**

```
printf
strings
echo
awk
sed
cat
```

Comment: Can you please explain what those two lines in the `for` loop actually do?

Comment: @kiner_shah 1st awk prints column1 if the line does not start with a comment/pound sign `#` 2nd awk changes the record seperator `RS` to `|` and `(` which then allows me to grab the other commands after a pipe `|` or open bracket `(` as column 1